# Ant Migration Tool: How to deploy metadata in source format

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata, ant

We are heavily relying on ant to do manual deployment and CI/CD in one of our projects.
But now time comes when we need to migrate from 1gp to 2gp package, thus we would need to switch from classic to source format metadata.

Is there anyway to deploy metadata in source format via ant migration tool? As a sort of temporary step while we are in the process of migration, i.e. before switching to sfdx completely.

So far, we've only found a way to convert source format to classic, but again that requires using sfdx command, which we would like to avoid doing at this stage.

In other words, as first step of migration, we would like to replace our classic code base with source format, but make it work with our current ant and CI/CD setup for now.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

No, the ANT migration tool only works with metadata format (which you call "classic" format), not source format.

The only method I know of to convert from source format to metadata format is to use sfdx.